# REGEX: Copy the content of a tag in another tag without loosing the content of the second tag

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I have this two tags, title and meta-description:

> `<title>My name</title>`
>
> `<meta name="description" content="I love my beautiful princess"/>`

I want to copy the content of `<meta name="description">` tag into the `<title>` tag, without loosing the content of the meta tag

So I made a regex for this:

Search: `<title>(.*?)</title>|<meta name="description" content="(.*?)"/>`

Replace by:  `<title>\2</title>`

The only problem in this case, is that I am loosing the content of meta tag.

So, my desire output should be:

> `<title>I love my beautiful princess</title>`
>
> `<meta name="description" content="I love my beautiful princess"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<title>.*?<\/title>.*?(<meta.*?content="(.*?)"\/>)
```

and replace by this:

```
<title>\2<\/title>\n\1
```

Or if you want to keep the rest of the spaces other contents as it is... ie. by any chance anything comes in between this two lines.. then you may do it:

```
<title>.*?<\/title>(.*?)(<meta.*?content="(.*?)"\/>)
```

and replace by this:

```
<title>\3<\/title>\1\2
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0qfQOZ/1/)

> Update

as per op's comment : To do vice versa, you can do this:

```
(<title>(.*?)<\/title>.*?)(<meta.*?content=").*?("\/>)
```

and replace by

```
\1\3\2\4
```

P.S: Make sure `. matches newline` is checked.

Comment: works, Rizwan. And if I want vice versa, so to copy the title in the meta? How can be change your regex?

Comment: @RobRob I have updated the answer as per your comment

Comment: Rizwan, another scenario for those who will want. Can you please make a regex for the scenario when I have two similar tags, like `<title>My name</title>` and `<h1>I love my beautiful princess</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have similar kind of tags, for example: `<title>` and `<h1>`.

. matches newline:

> SEARCH:  `<title>.*?<\/title>(.*?)(<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>)`
>
> REPLACE BY: `<title>\3<\/title>\1\2`

and vice versa

. matches newline:

> SEARCH:  `(<title>(.*?)<\/title>.*?)(<h1>).*?(<\/h1>)`
>
> REPLACE BY   `\1\3\2\4`